# Can anyone please help how to write this code on Python?

Tags: python

Create a counter that takes in a number from the user, counts from 0 to that number, tells the user as it counts if each number is even or odd, then sums all the numbers together and prints the sum.

The following code and comments are a starting point. The text following each # is a comment, you will need to replace the comments with the necessary code:

```py
count = 0
sum = 0
num = 0

# Ask user for a number

#All code lines that need to be inside the while loop, need to be tabbed over once.

while (count <= num):
     # add count to sum

     # Use the following if statement along with the remainder 
     # operator (modulus, %) to check if a number is even or odd.
     if count % 2 != 0:
          #print the number is odd
     else:
          #print the number is even

     # update counter for the while loop exit condition
     count = count + 1 

#print the sum
```

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I highly suggest reading [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so the community can better help you.

Comment: See also [homework guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: I tried but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using for loop

```
count=0
sum=0

for i in range(0,n+1):
    if (i%2==0):
        print("Number is Even")
    else:
        print("Number is Odd")
    
    sum+=i

print(sum)
```

Using While loop:

```
count=0
sum=0

while(count<n):
    if(count%2==0):
        print("Number is Even")
    else:
        print("Number is odd")
    
    count+=1
    sum+=count
    
print(sum)
```

Comment: @Alex does this solve your question?
Kindly accept the answer if yes.